Find the limit of $ x_n= \frac{a^{2n}}{(1+a)(1+a^3)…(1+a^{2n+1})} $, when $a>0$
I have tried to approach it by squeezing between two other sequences with the same limit but I can’t find a good way to do this. Also I am a little confused because $a>0$ and that means I should take two cases, when $0<a<1$ and when $a>1$, right?
I also studied the monotony and I got $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{a^2}{1+a^{2n+3}}<1$ which tells me that the sequence is decreasing and then $x_1>x_n$ but again that doesn’t seem to help very much.
I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

By ratio test we have

for $0<a<1$ we have$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{a^2}{1+a^{2n+3}}\to a^2<1$
for $a=1$ we have$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{1}{2}<1$
for $a>1$ we have$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{a^2}{1+a^{2n+3}}\to 0$

therefore in all cases $x_n \to 0$.

I love short concise answers such as this one. +1

@Mike Thanks, we don't need more than that! ;)

If $0<a<1,$ then the numerator of the expression for $x_n$ tends to $0$, whilst the denominator is always $\geq 1,$ so $x_n\to 0.$
If $a=1,$ then the numerator is $1,$ whilst the denominator is $2^{n+1}$. Again, $x_n\to 0.$
For $a>1,$ I first tried to use Bernoulli's generalised (base) inequality, but I failed to get anywhere with it. But there is an easier way. Observe that
$$ (1+a)\left(1+a^3\right)\left(1+a^5\right)\ldots\left(1+a^{2n-3}\right)\left(1+a^{2n-1}\right)\left(1+a^{2n+1}\right)\geq a^\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}k\right) = a^{(n+1)^2}. $$
Thus, $x_n \leq a^{2n-(n+1)^2}\to 0$ if $a>1.$
An equivalent way to write the last part is:
$$ \log x_n  = 2n\log a - \log \left( (1+a)\left( 1+a^3\right) \cdots\left(1+a^{2n-1}\right)\left(1+a^{2n+1}\right)\right) $$
$$ = 2n\log a - \left(\log(1+a) + \log\left(1+a^3 \right)+\cdots+\log\left(1+a^{2n-1}\right)+\log\left(1+a^{2n+1}\right)\right) $$
$$ \leq 2n\log a - \left(\log(a) + \log\left(a^3 \right)+\cdots+\log\left(a^{2n-1}\right)+\log\left(a^{2n+1}\right)\right) $$
$$ = 2n\log a - \left(\log(a) + 3\log\left(a \right)+\cdots+(2n-1)\log\left(a\right)+(2n+1)\log\left(a\right)\right) $$
$$ = \left(2n - (n+1)^2\right)\log a\to -\infty \text{ if } a>1.$$
Since $\log(x_n)\to -\infty$ as $n\to \infty,$ it follows that $x_n\to 0^+.$

Modeling after user.
If $0 < a < 1$ then
$x_n < a^{2n}
\to 0$.
If $a=1$ then
$x_n = \frac1{2^{2n+1}}
\to 0$.
If $a>1$ then
$x_n
\le \dfrac{a^{2n}}{(1+a^{2n})(1+a^{2n+1})}
\lt \dfrac{1}{(1+a^{2n+1})}
\to 0$.
